# Use Docker-Windows for Gitlab-runner

Tags: c++, docker, gitlab

I'm trying to use Docker in Windows to create a Gitlab-Runner to build a C++ application. It works so far, but I guess there are better aproaches. Here's what I did:

Here's my initial Docker Container:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:2004

# Restore the default Windows shell for correct batch processing.
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

# Download the Build Tools bootstrapper.
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vs_buildtools.exe C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe

# Install Build Tools with the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.AzureBuildTools workload, excluding workloads and components with known issues.
RUN C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache `
    --installPath C:\BuildTools `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64 `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CMake.Project `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.19041 `
    --locale en-US `
 || IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0

# Define the entry point for the docker container.
# This entry point starts the developer command prompt and launches the PowerShell shell.
ENTRYPOINT ["cmd","/k", "C:\\BuildTools\\VC\\Auxiliary\\Build\\vcvars64.bat", "&&", "powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

And my .gitlab-ci.yml looks like this:

```
build Docker Windows:
  image: buildtools2019_core
  stage: build
  tags:
    - win-docker
  script:
    - mkdir build
    - cd build
    - cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DenableWarnings=ON  -G Ninja -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=Ninja ../
    - ninja
```

This works so far and everthing builds correctly. The main problem however is that if the build fails the job succeeds anyways. I suspect that my entrypoint is wrong because powershell is executed inside of a cmd and only the exit code of cmd is checked which always succeeds.

So I tried to use powershell directly as entrypoint. I need to set environment variables via vcvars64.bat but that is not that trivial to do. I tried to execute the "Developer Powershell for VS 2019" but I can't execute the link in the entrypoint directly and the link looks like this:

```
"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noe -c "&{Import-Module """C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll"""; Enter-VsDevShell 6f66c5f6}"
```

Which I don't quit understand what it does and the hash also varies from installation to installation. Also simply using this as entrypoint didn't work.
I then tried to use the Invoke-Environment Script taken from "https://github.com/nightroman/PowerShelf/blob/master/Invoke-Environment.ps1". This allows me to execute the .bat file from powershell like this:

```
Invoke-Environment C:\\BuildTools\\VC\\Auxiliary\\Build\\vcvars64.bat
```

But to do this I need to add this function to my profile, as far as I understood. I did this by copying it to "C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1" so that it would be accessible by all users.

In my Docker file I added:

```
COPY Invoke-Environment.ps1 C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1
```

and replaced the entrypoint with:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", "-NoExit", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass", "Invoke-Environment C:\\BuildTools\\VC\\Auxiliary\\Build\\vcvars64.bat"]
```

But that didn't initialize the environment variables correctly. Also "Invoke-Environment" is not found by the gitlab-runner. My last resort was to write a small script (Init64.ps1) that executes the Invoke-Environment function with vcvars64.bat:

```
function Invoke-Environment {
    param
    (
        # Any cmd shell command, normally a configuration batch file.
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $Command
    )

    $Command = "`"" + $Command + "`""
    cmd /c "$Command > nul 2>&1 && set" | . { process {
        if ($_ -match '^([^=]+)=(.*)') {
            [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($matches[1], $matches[2])
        }
    }}
}

Invoke-Environment C:\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat
```

I copied this in docker via:

```
COPY Init64.ps1 Init64.ps1
```

and used this entrypoint:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"]
```

In my build script I need to manually call it to setup the variables:

```
build Docker Windows:
  image: buildtools2019_core
  stage: build
  tags:
    - win-docker
  script:
    - C:\Init64.ps1
    - mkdir build
    - cd build
    - cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DenableWarnings=ON  -G Ninja -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=Ninja ../
    - ninja
```

Now everything works as intended the build works and the job only succeeds if the build succeeds.

However, I would prefer to setup my environment in the entrypoint so that I don't have to do this in my build script.

Is there a better way to do this? Also feel free to suggest any improvements I could make.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some struggling, here is my `entry.bat` that correctly loads the environment exports the error-level/return-value:

```bat
REM Load environment
call C:\\BuildTools\\VC\\Auxiliary\\Build\\vcvars64.bat

REM If there are no parameters call cmd
IF [%1] == [] GOTO NOCALL

REM If there are parameters call cmd with /S for it to exit directly
cmd /S /C "%*"
exit %errorlevel%

:NOCALL
cmd
exit %errorlevel%
```